# QueryDSL + SpringData + JPA : Filter not working on inner entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

In my spring boot maven project, i added **QueryDSL** + **SpringData** + **JPA** support.

**Added two repositories**

1. StudentRespository

   public interface StudentRespository extends JpaRepository, QueryDslPredicateExecutor {

   }
2. CourseRepository

   public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository, QueryDslPredicateExecutor {

   }

**In JPA model class,** mapping between Student and Course is defined with OneToMany relationship (in my case, a student contains list of courses)

**Table structure is**

1. Student [ID, Name, Age]
2. Course [ID, StudentID, Name, Hours]

**I want to query data using URL only.**

**Currently,**

I'm able to get all students by
http://localhost:9000/students

Able to get specific student by 
http://localhost:9000/students/1

Able to get filter student by
http://localhost:9000/students?Name=John

Able to get courses of specific student by
http://localhost:9000/students/1/courses

**Now,**

I want to apply filter on courses that are receiving for that student. 
means *http://localhost:9000/students/1/courses?Name=English*

But, it is not working and returning all courses associated to that student. while i'm expecting only the courses which contains 'English' in 'Name' field (among that student courses).

Can anyone help me in achieving this functionality ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the query that does not return the expected result.

Comment: I'm achieving that from url, means applying filter from url, no query is added (as i added my repo files are also empty). As you know that QueryDSL also works without writing query by adding filter from URL.

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks for the info!

Comment: like https://gist.github.com/olivergierke/decf03d4948cd58a51bc